# Deleting row from table without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have page where it displays a list of orders. I'm trying deleting row of the table when a user clicks on a button, but its just removing the first row and when i try to delete the second or third row it cannot be delete it. Can anyone please help me or point me in to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

View:

```
<table id="Tableitem" class="table">
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="product-title">
                <a href="/Main/Produktdetaljer/@item.ProductId?proid=@item.ProductId">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="base-price price-box"> 
                        <span class="price"> 
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price) 
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="QuantityOfProduct@(item.ProductId)">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
        </td>
       <td>
       <i data-id="@item.ProductId" class="fa fa-trash cart-remove-item removeproduct"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascipt:

```
$("i.removeproduct").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var productId = $(this).data("id");
    var url = "/cart/RemoveProduct";

    $.get(url, { productId: productId }, function (data) {
         // i used .load for not refreshing page
        $('#Tableitem').load(document.URL + ' #Tableitem');

        });         
});
```

Comment: `$("#Tableitem").on('click' , "i.removeproduct" , function (e){` instead of `$("i.removeproduct").click(function (e) {`  take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: thanks. its working fine :)

Comment: You'r welcome @TheFirst .. Have a great day :)

Comment: tnx n you to ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

or

```
 $(this).closest('tr').remove()
```

it's up to you.

Comment: ya Mohammed he try to delete the row with `$.get` then load the whole table again without the deleted row .. so he just need to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)